# How To Fire Mysql query using ajax and jquery and generate dynamic tree view.?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, treeview

I want to try make course detail tree view like
on clicking on 10, 12-Diploma-ITI is display in new division
if click on ITI ther is generat new division with child of ITI From database.

on clicking on 12, Commerce-Arts-Degree is display
and every child have sub chiled and hide and show on clicking event using jquery.

So how can i fire query on clicking on button and display perticulor cource's sub-cources using ajax and php mysql...

Thanx In advance

Comment: What is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Emz I don't strat to coad now but i want some advice how it's done good and reliable b'coz i am beginner in MVC so i am canfuse what is best for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/"getJSON") to get the data. You will need to setup an endpoint using PHP that can read the data out of your database and return it in a useful format.

Once you have the data, you can look at [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/) for a nice way to display trees of information.

Comment: Thanx Gareth, I appreciate your answer and it's  proper :), but i need the result not in directory form, i need it in hierarchy and i near to solve it. i thankful to you for answer it will be useful for me or someone else in future because knowledge not die bro. :)